# IIS is giving me wrong pysical path suddenly. It worked before. Asp.Net

Tags: asp.net, .net, iis, asp.net-web-api, .net-4.0

I am working in my project a while from now, my IIS and WebAPI configuration were all set. When I was going to test a new endpoint, all my endpoints were not working, I can't even know why. **It worked fine before, and I didn't change anything in config**.

Web.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301879
  -->
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />

  <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 --></configSections>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.6.1" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.6.1" />
  </system.web>
  <!-- Para validar put e delete-->
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-12.0.0.0" newVersion="12.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.6.5135.21930" newVersion="1.6.5135.21930" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Http" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.2.7.0" newVersion="5.2.7.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Net.Http.Formatting" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.2.7.0" newVersion="5.2.7.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Antlr3.Runtime" publicKeyToken="eb42632606e9261f" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.5.0.2" newVersion="3.5.0.2" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-5.2.7.0" newVersion="5.2.7.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Numerics.Vectors" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.1.4.0" newVersion="4.1.4.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Net.Http" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.2.0.0" newVersion="4.2.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Memory" publicKeyToken="cc7b13ffcd2ddd51" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.1.0" newVersion="4.0.1.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.4.0" newVersion="4.0.4.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Security.Cryptography.Algorithms" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.3.0.0" newVersion="4.3.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.IO.Compression" publicKeyToken="b77a5c561934e089" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.2.0.0" newVersion="4.2.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Security.Cryptography.Primitives" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.2.0" newVersion="4.0.2.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.IO.FileSystem" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.3.0" newVersion="4.0.3.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="mssqllocaldb" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
  <connectionStrings>
    <!-- <add name="CoreEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Data.CoreDB.csdl|res://*/Data.CoreDB.ssdl|res://*/Data.CoreDB.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=*********;initial catalog=clone;persist security info=True;user id=***********;password=********;multipleactiveresultsets=True;application name=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />--><!--<add name="CoreEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Data.CoreDB.csdl|res://*/Data.CoreDB.ssdl|res://*/Data.CoreDB.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=*********;initial catalog=core;user id=******;password=*******;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" /></connectionStrings>-->
    <add name="CoreEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Data.CoreDB.csdl|res://*/Data.CoreDB.ssdl|res://*/Data.CoreDB.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=*******;initial catalog=corepetro;user id=**********;password=*******;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
    <add name="cloneEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Data.CoreTestDB.csdl|res://*/Data.CoreTestDB.ssdl|res://*/Data.CoreTestDB.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=*********;initial catalog=clone;persist security info=True;user id=******;password=*******;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" /></connectionStrings>

<system.webServer>
  <httpProtocol>
    <customHeaders>
      <!--<add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
      <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE" />
      <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization" />-->
    </customHeaders>
  </httpProtocol>
  <handlers>
    <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
    <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
    <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" />
    <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
  </handlers>
</system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Global.asax.cs

```
namespace clubpetroapi
{
    public class WebApiApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
    {
        protected void Application_Start()
        {
            GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
        }
    }
}
```

RouteConfig:

```
namespace clubpetroapi
{
    public class RouteConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
    }
}
```

Controller that I'm trying to access:

```
 public class RulesFraudCrontroller : ApiController 
    {
        [EnableCors(origins: "*", headers: "*", methods: "*")]
        [Route("rules")]
        [HttpPost]
        public IHttpActionResult InsertRule([FromUri] string idstore, [FromUri] string token)
        {
            try
            {
                var rule = new Data.TB_RULES_FRAUD();
                var service = new Services.RulesFraudService();
                var response = service.InsertRule(idstore,rule, token);
                switch (response.Cod)
                {
                    case 200: return Ok(response.Obj); //Usuário desativado
                    case 400: return new StatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, this); //Solicitação inválida
                    case 401: return new StatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized, this); //Sem permissão
                    case 403: return new StatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.Forbidden, this);
                    case 404: return new StatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, this); //Usuário não encontrado
                    case 405: return new StatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.MethodNotAllowed, this); //metodo não permitido
                    case 500: return new StatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, this); //Erro interno de servidor
                    default: return InternalServerError();
                }


            }
            catch (Exception E)
            {
                return InternalServerError(E);
            }
        }

    }
```

When I try to access my endpoint using the address as a POST method:

localhost:56495/rules?idstore=2&token=master

It gives me the following page, sorry for the portuguese:

[Image.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pTgcV.png)

Note the physical path that is trying to reach, it should not be like that, but I can't know how to fix it.

**I am using .net framework 4.6.1**

Comment: "Note the physical path that is trying to reach, it should not be like that", then what path do you expect? Why cannot you modify IIS configuration to get it right?

Comment: How can I change de configuration of IIS express?

Comment: Either you learn how to edit the config file manually, or you use a tool like Jexus Manager, https://docs.jexusmanager.com/getting-started/features.html

Comment: You guys are missing the point. Some of my endpoints work, and now some don't. I didn't change anything.

Answer (score 0):

You use HttpPost. If you use HttpPost, you don't request with query string (localhost:56495/rules?idstore=2&token=master). You should use HttpGet. Or you can try to send a HttpPost request with Postman.

Comment: That's what I am trying to do, even though it gives me error 404.

Comment: Ok. Try this. localhost:56495/RulesFraud/rules?idstore=2&token=master

Comment: Same thing, and the address is supposed to be the safe as as the [Route()] tag is. which is rule.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried changing the endpoint to a "GET", and putting a debug point on that endpoint, to see if it gets hit?